# How to filter results in Chef Search API

Tags: rest, search, filter, chef-infra

Chef Node API, like /nodes/nodename will return the full node object like:

```
{
  "name": "node_name",
  "chef_environment": "_default",
  "run_list": [
    "recipe[recipe_name]"
  ]
  "json_class": "Chef::Node",
  "chef_type": "node",
  "automatic": { ... },
  "normal": { "tags": [ ] },
  "default": { },
  "override": { "cookbook1_name"=>{
                    "attribute1"=>"overridevalue"
              }}
}
```

I am trying to use Chef::Search::Query.search REST API to just return a few required columns instead of full node object. For example:

```
Chef::Search::Query.new("server url").search(:node, '*:*', :filter_result => {'name' => ['name'] } )
```

It works that will return the node name only, but when I try to add the override data, it always return null...

```
Chef::Search::Query.new("server url").search(:node, '*:*', :filter_result => {'name' => ['name'], 'override' => ['override'] } )
```

It seems that the filter_result can work for type like string, or array, but override is a json object, how to include it in result?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

et The key path in `filter_result` is run against the merged attribute form. You would want something like `'attribute1' => ['cookbook1_name', 'attribute1']`.

EDIT:

For a direct example:

```
$ knife node show foo -z -l -Fj
{
  "name": "foo",
  "chef_environment": "_default",
  "run_list": [

]
,
  "normal": {

  },
  "default": {

  },
  "override": {
    "key1": {
      "key2": "value"
    }
  },
  "automatic": {

  }
}
$ knife exec -z -E 'puts search(:node, "*:*").inspect'
[#<Chef::Node:0x007f89e3ee97f0 @chef_server_rest=nil, @name="foo", @chef_environment="_default", @primary_runlist=#<Chef::RunList:0x007f89e3ee9728 @run_list_items=[]>, @override_runlist=#<Chef::RunList:0x007f89e3ee9660 @run_list_items=[]>, @policy_name=nil, @policy_group=nil, @attributes=#<Chef::Node::Attribute @default={}, @env_default={}, @role_default={}, @force_default={}, @normal={}, @override={"key1"=>{"key2"=>"value"}}, @role_override={}, @env_override={}, @force_override={}, @automatic={}, @merged_attributes=nil, @properties=nil>, @run_state={}>]
$ knife exec -z -E 'puts search(:node, "*:*", filter_result: {myval: %w{key1 key2}}).inspect'
[{"myval"=>"value"}]
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried to dump the node attributes from the Chef REST API, what I found is that in Node object, there are attributes like name, chef_environment, override, default, and automatic, in my experiment, it seems like the filter_result can only support the sub attributes within automatic (like hostname, fqdn, roles, etc) and other simple type attributes like chef_environment, name, but can not access to the override attribute.

Comment: That is not correct, you are just using the wrong code for it. All attributes should work with the system.

Comment: could you please help share a runnable query to get the override value of a node? thanks!

Comment: Again, you can't _specifically_ get override values, but it operates on the whole merged object so just access it as you normally would.

Comment: thanks for your code! In my case, it is a bit difficult to me, because the key1 and key2 will be quite dynamic.... anyway thanks a lot!

Comment: If the keys aren't fixed, there may not be a ton of value in using filter_result. You can at least grab only a subset of the attribute tree and then process it locally.

Comment: I am quite new to Chef, and using Chef REST API in Java to get these data. In my simple understanding, the /nodes/<node_name> REST API will return all attributes of the node, specially a bunch of information about CPU, memory, device etc that are not useful to me. How I can grab only a subset of the attribute tree for a node object? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Same `filter_result` feature, but just give a partial key path and you'll get back the hash from below that point.

Comment: Thanks for your patience! I am too naive to understand... could you give me an example?  thanks!